# How to loop through two list dictionaries to append unique key values to one list dict and continue through other with shared repeating value entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I'm having trouble figuring out how to merge unique key values from one list dict to another list dict in which the dictionaries have repeating values.

The two list dicts are generated from different sources that have some  repeating "name" values and don't always follow the same index. So there are times when a correlating set of key values appears in one list dict further in its index (or possibly earlier). Also, the two list dicts may not be the same length with one containing more entries than the other.

I've tried a few nested loops, but I can't seem to figure out how to handle simultaneous indexing and restarting the loop for entires that have not yet matched. I'd also receive an error at the end because of the mismatching range in list dictionaries.

Here's what I tried:

```
listOne = [{'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'aaa'},
           {'name': 'Article 2', 'description': 'bbb'},
           {'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'abb'},
           {'name': 'Article 3 series', 'description': 'cccc'}]

listTwo = [{'name': 'Article 1 series', 'link': 'www.google.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 2', 'link': 'www.yahoo.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 3 series', 'link': 'www.bing.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 1 series', 'link': 'www.google.com/test'},
           {'name': 'Article 4', 'link': 'www.duckduckgo.com'}]

firstList = len(listOne)
secondList = len(listTwo)

while listTwo:    
     for i in range(firstList):
         if i <= secondList:
             if listOne[i]["name"] == listTwo[0]["name"]:
                 print("found")
                 listOne.append(listTwo[0]["link"])
             else:
                 continue
         else:
             break
     listTwo.pop(0)
```

Ultimately, as "name" key values are matched I'd like to merge the "link" key value into the corresponding found listOne index. Otherwise look for the previous unmatched or next matching "name" key value. If no "name" key value exists in listOne or all of the indexes in listOne have been matched, then stop the loop and drop any remaining entires from listTwo.

So listOne should look like this:

```
listOne = [{'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'aaa','link': 'www.google.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 2', 'description': 'bbb', 'link': 'www.yahoo.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'abb', 'link': 'www.google.com/test'},
           {'name': 'Article 3 series', 'description': 'cccc', 'link': 'www.bing.com'}]
```

Comment: `Article 1 series` is repeated twice. How do you know which one to merge?

Comment: Good point. Maybe adding a simple check in for loop like ```if listOne[i]["link"] is None:``` then merge. My hope would be to continue merging the "link" key values into listOne hoping that they'll correctly correspond to each particular index entry.

Comment: I suspect that `listOne` and `listTwo` are indexed the same way. If I take item at index X in the first and second list, then I have two pieces of information (dictionaries) are concerning the same thing?

Comment: is link unique in your generated list of dicts?

Comment: @cglacet not necessarily. I have found that there are some entries that are left out of listOne which causes an index mismatch with listTwo. Other times I've seen that listTwo indexed a few entries earlier than those in listOne. But for now I'd just want to merge the "link" key values into each listOne index entry.

Comment: @Umesh yes, the link is always unique in listTwo

Comment: If the items are not ordered and names are not unique then there is no solution to this. You need one of these to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have tried, you have just one flaw which is not giving you the required result.

> listOne.append(listTwo[0]["link"])

You are appending the *value* of the *link* to *listOne*.

Or in other terms, you are appending `www.google.com` to `listOne`. Whereas, you want them to be as a key-value pair in `listOne[i]`.

Hence, your result is showing up of this sorts:

> [{'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'aaa'}, {'name': 'Article 2', 'description': 'bbb'}, {'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'abb'}, {'name': 'Article 3 series', 'description': 'cccc'}, 'www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.bing.com', 'www.google.com/test', 'www.google.com/test']

As clearly seen above, your *link* is getting appended to *listOne*.

However, if you add the key-value pair to the dictionary (in your case `listOne[i]`), your code will work perfectly. (The key being *'link'* and the value being *listTwo[i]['link']*)

Here is the corrected code:

```
listOne = [{'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'aaa'},
           {'name': 'Article 2', 'description': 'bbb'},
           {'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'abb'},
           {'name': 'Article 3 series', 'description': 'cccc'}]

listTwo = [{'name': 'Article 1 series', 'link': 'www.google.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 2', 'link': 'www.yahoo.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 3 series', 'link': 'www.bing.com'},
           {'name': 'Article 1 series', 'link': 'www.google.com/test'},
           {'name': 'Article 4', 'link': 'www.duckduckgo.com'}]


while listTwo:
    for i in range(len(listOne)):
        if i >= len(listTwo):
            break
        if not 'link' in listOne[i].keys():
            if listOne[i]['name'] == listTwo[i]['name']:
                print('found')
                listOne[i]['link'] = listTwo[i]['link']
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue

    listTwo.pop(0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I ended up adding a key value for dates then used that to help sort the two list dicts and then follow your changes. The only revision was that I edited the if statement to include the date in order to distinguish between repeated names ```if listOne[i]["name"] == listTwo[i]["name"] and listOne[i]["date"] == listTwo[i]["date"]:``` Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can simply do this:

```py
merged =[{**one, **two} for one, two in zip(listOne, listTwo)]
print(merged)
```

Which outputs :

```
[
   {'name': 'Article 1 series', 'description': 'aaa', 'link': 'www.google.com'},
   {'name': 'Article 2', 'description': 'bbb', 'link': 'www.yahoo.com'}, 
   ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks @cglacet. It seemed to work for the example list dicts, but when I trying it on my data sets it worked for some indexes while merging and modifying others key values incorrectly. If I had a "date" key value, would it be possible to sort and order the list dicts in such a way that unique names wouldn't matter?

Comment: What you need is something that makes it possible to relate dictionaries from the first list to dictionaries of the second. Anything that would allow a human to tell how to pair them would do :p. So yes, if dates are matching that would allow us to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Luckily there were key values for dates for both list dicts which allowed me to sort and merge. I ended up following @Pranav's correction to my previous code and it appears to be working now. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have huge lists then start using pandas

```
from pandas as pd
one_df = pd.DataFrame(listOne)

OUTPUT:
  description              name
0         aaa  Article 1 series
1         bbb         Article 2
2         abb  Article 1 series
3        cccc  Article 3 series


second_df = pd.DataFrame(listTwo)

OUTPUT:
                  link              name
0       www.google.com  Article 1 series
1        www.yahoo.com         Article 2
2         www.bing.com  Article 3 series
3  www.google.com/test  Article 1 series
4   www.duckduckgo.com         Article 4

merged_df = df.groupby("link").first()

OUTPUT:
                    description              name
link                                             
www.bing.com               cccc  Article 3 series
www.google.com              aaa  Article 1 series
www.google.com/test         aaa  Article 1 series
www.yahoo.com               bbb         Article 2

 data = []
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
    data_dict = {}
    data_dict["link"] = index
    data_dict["description"] = row.description
    data_dict["name"] = row.name
    data.append(data_dict)

OUTPUT of data: 
[{'description': 'cccc', 'link': 'www.bing.com', 'name': 'www.bing.com'},
 {'description': 'aaa', 'link': 'www.google.com', 'name': 'www.google.com'},
 {'description': 'aaa', 'link': 'www.google.com/test', 'name': 'www.google.com/test'},
 {'description': 'bbb', 'link': 'www.yahoo.com', 'name': 'www.yahoo.com'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up going with @Pranav's correction to my original code, but I'll keep pandas in mind for the future.